# Passing an image through a Lambda function to invoke a sagemaker endpoint

Tags: image, api, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sagemaker

im trying to invoke a sagemaker endpoint passing in the image from a POST request using this lambda function but whenever i make the request using postman i get this error

```
{
"message": "Could not parse request body into json: Could not parse payload into json: Unexpected character (\'/\' (code 47)): maybe a (non-standard) comment? (not recognized as one since Feature \'ALLOW_COMMENTS\' not enabled for parser)\n at [Source: (byte[])\"/9j/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8UHRofHh0aHBwgJC4nICIsIxwcKDcpLDAxNDQ0Hyc5PTgyPC4zNDL/wAAUCAEAAQAEABEAAREAAhEAAxEA/8QAGwAAAwEBAAMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgf/xAAwEAACAgEEAgEEAQQDAAMBAQAAAQIRIQMSMUEiUWETMnGBkQQjQqGxwdEz8PFS4f/aAA4EAAABAAIAAwAAPwD5/Bf3MnpKj/cyehKPlZ9/NJxSzRcoqMW0htJAT9Zvxr/ZL1W4pdsFK8ATmLTwKKyn0L9IC4yc3Zae52WgNn9uTV5gU3aA55OMZXRzzpO3VGUqTQF/VlJY4K+o2sFN4Azbblkh23chctNgbx4wbrhMvL/AFRbcPwUncR/40gJhPdK/REZbpEp5AU3JWmKTkmD3LkDXQ1Nqt8FaU68ioTrLAnUlukmhaktzQpPdICO38Ci8tPoXDAmdxVoJ\"[truncated 15352 bytes]; line: 1, column: 2]"
```

}

here's my lambda function

```
import os
import io
import boto3
import json
import csv

# grab environment variables
ENDPOINT_NAME = os.environ['ENDPOINT_NAME']
runtime= boto3.client('runtime.sagemaker')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))
    
    data = json.loads(json.dumps(event))
    payload = base64.b64encode(data['data-binary'])
    response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=ENDPOINT_NAME,Body=payload)
    print(response)
    result = json.loads(response['Body'].read())
    
    return result
```

can you show me how to properly implement this?

Comment: Please read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get a faster and more accurate answer.